# Modem software install problem

Tags: usb-modem, mobile-broadband, 4g

Did an update to Ubuntu 16.04LTS yesterday unfortunately now Ubuntu is giving the messages:

> Optus 4G Mobile” contains software intended to be automatically started. Would you like to run it?

and

> Oops! There was a problem running this software. Unable to locate program.

Have used terminal to enter as root, navigated to the `linux_mbb_install` directory i.e. `Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install/` but entering and executing install does not do what is required.

Any suggestions?

Optus E3372 4G USB modem has:

```
Optus 4G Mobile/HiLink.app
Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install
Optus 4G Mobile/MobileBrServ
Optus 4G Mobile/ArConfig.dat
Optus 4G Mobile/autorun.sh
Optus 4G Mobile/AutoRun.exe
Optus 4G Mobile/AUTORUN.INF
Optus 4G Mobile/install_linux
Optus 4G Mobile/Startup.ico


Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install/7zr
Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install/ArConfig.dat
Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install/install
Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install/mbbservice.bin
Optus 4G Mobile/linux_mbb_install/readme.txt
```

Comment: Have tried copying the software to HDD, some joy but still no connection.